# jquery/livequery not working in this particular case

Tags: jquery, livequery

Using jquery, all of my other livequery functions work fine, i am getting an error for this particular one...

```
$("[class*='welcome']").livequery("click", function(e){   etc.......
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'livequery'
```

is it because of the wildcard? or a general jquery error?

Thank you

Comment: updated to reflect correct error.. :)

Comment: What is `livequery`? Is it a plugin?

Comment: do you include `livequery` in your document? and wrap all of your jQuery code within `$(document).ready(function() { .. })`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you want to do is

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future

Then this is the appropriate syntax:

```
$(document).on("click", "[class*='welcome']", function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

jQuery's [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function used to be the way to go, but it has been deprecated in favor of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as of jQuery 1.7.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/zNXXk/